# sed: why doesn't dot/asterisk match utf8 character

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, sed

I would like to understand why dot/asterisk fails to match an utf8 character in sed commands:

```
$ echo "begin remove � end" | sed 's/remove.*//'
begin � end
```

(expected result should be `begin` )

Is it because � character (U+00E0 à) is represented in 3 bytes?

Comment: Funny, I do get the exact output you want using your commands.

Comment: What version of `sed` do you run?

Comment: Works as expected under Cygwin with GNU sed 4.2.1. What OS are you using (output of `uname -sr`)?

Comment: try `echo "begin remove � end" | LANG= sed 's/remove.*//'` Got to run. Good luck.

Comment: sed _does_ remove the `�`, at least it does under Arch Linux.